# find all coprime sets with size $m \leq n$

Tags: number-theory

I am trying to find all sets of size $m$ with elements in $\{1, 2, 3, \dots n\}$ such that all of the elements in the set are pairwise coprime.

I would like to find the number of sets as well as the actual sets themselves for a given $m, n$.

Is there any formula to do this?

e.g. $ n = 5,\; m = 2$,

The sets are  $\{1,2\},\{1,3\},\{1,4\},\{1,5\}, \{2,3\},\{2,5\},\{3,4\},\{3,5\},\{4,5\}$

And there are $9$ sets.

The time complexity would be nice as well..

Thanks

Comment: Look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18790284/how-to-calculate-the-number-of-coprime-subsets-of-the-set-1-2-3-n)